# wordpress contact form 7 disable email

Tags: php, wordpress

I am facing an issue with [Contact Form 7 for Wordpress](http://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). I want to disable the email notification which i did using

```
demo_mode: on
```

At the same time i want to redirect on submit which i used to do using

```
on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/about-us/';"
```

Both would work when used individually.But i want to use both at the same time.

I tried doing

```
    on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/about-us/';" 
demo_mode: on
```

Doesnt seem to work. Kindly advice.

Comment: None of the 'experts' here seem to know head or tail about this issue...

Comment: I don't have it in front of me to test.. Try adding a comma between the two values and see if that works. `on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/about-us/';", demo_mode: on`

Comment: The "experts" do know .. but you need to give it some time . Look at my answer .

Answer (score 12):

The plugin author has changed as of at least 4.0 the way you should do this again. The `skip_mail` property is now private :

```
class WPCF7_Submission {
    private $skip_mail = false;
    ...
}
```

You should use this filter : `wpcf7_skip_mail`

For example :

```
function my_skip_mail($f){
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    if(/* YOUR TEST HERE */){
        return true; // DO NOT SEND E-MAIL
    }
}
add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','my_skip_mail');
```

Comment: The filter can actually be activated from action bound to `wpcf7_before_send_mail` as well, just add it anywhere in the action hook as `add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','__return_true');`

Answer (score 4):

The author of the plugin `Contact Form 7` has refactored some of the code for its version 3.9 and since then the callback function for the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` must be written differently.

To prevent Contact Form 7 from sending the email and force it to redirect after the form has been submitted, please have a look at the following piece of code (for version >= 3.9):

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', wpcf7_disablEmailAndRedirect );

function wpcf7_disablEmailAndRedirect( $cf7 ) {
    // get the contact form object
    $wpcf7 = WPCF7_ContactForm::get_current();

    // do not send the email
    $wpcf7->skip_mail = true;

    // redirect after the form has been submitted
    $wpcf7->set_properties( array(
        'additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"location.replace('http://example.com//');\"",
    ) );
}
```

Comment: hello @mike, i came across your answer and i am trying your suggestion but my form isn't being redirected and i see the "your message....success" but the form isn't not redirect. I was able to skip email

Comment: @alex That is weird because this is the code I'm using in my plugins and I have no problem... The only difference is that I also access another WPCF7 object to get the values of the fields of the form.

Did you check your browser's console to see if there's a javascript error?

Anyway, the code that I use in real projects looks like this:
`$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
if( $submission ) {
 // do something with the fields info
}
$wpcf7->set_properties( array(
    'additional_settings' => "on_sent_ok: \"http://example.com/\"",
) );`

Answer (score 2):

Hook into `wpcf7_before_send_mail` instead of using the flag .

```
 add_action("wpcf7_before_send_mail", "wpcf7_disablemail");  

    function wpcf7_disablemail(&$wpcf7_data) {  

        // this is just to show you $wpcf7_data and see all the stored data ..!  
        var_dump($wpcf7_data);  // disable this line

        // If you want to skip mailing the data..  
        $wpcf7_data->skip_mail = true;  

    }
```

Comment: Parameter 1 to wpcf7_disablemail() expected to be a reference, value given

Comment: @theJinX the answer is 5 years old, and i did not  confirmed it with any new version since . but you can try to drop the reference and see if it works ..

Answer (score 1):

Just an update. The following works in 4.1.1.

```
 on_sent_ok: "location = 'http://domain.com/about-us/';" 
 demo_mode: on
```

Answer (score 1):

There might have been a change to contact-form-7, because I wasn't able to access the $skip_mail variable in the  WPCF7_Submission object. I looked at the submission.php object in the \wp-content\plugins\contact-form-7\includes\submission.php file and found this:

```
private $skip_mail = false;
```

Since the variable is private, and there are no getters or setters in the file, you're not going to be able to change it externally. Just change it to this:

```
public $skip_mail = false;
```

and then you can change the variable like this in your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_custom_form_action_url');

function wpcf7_custom_form_action_url( $form)
{
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    $submission->skip_mail = true;

}
```

A reminder, if you update the contact-form-7 plugin, it will probably nullify your change, so keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Set `skip_mail: on` does the trick.

Comment: in 2022 this is the way to go. Just put this line in the Advanced settings area.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple code**

Copy and paste the following code in your activated theme functions.php file.

```
add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','__return_true');
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE WPCF7 ver. 7.5:** There is now a filter specifically to handle this.

```
function my_skip_mail($f){
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();
    $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

    if (/* do your testing here*/){
        return true; // DO NOT SEND E-MAIL
    }
}
add_filter('wpcf7_skip_mail','my_skip_mail');
```